# TypeScript import class from another project / module?

Tags: javascript, ruby, typescript, npm, typescript2.0

I am trying to alter the following build task written in Typescript in the following project:
https://github.com/Microsoft/app-store-vsts-extension/blob/master/Tasks/app-store-promote/app-store-promote.ts

I need an import like the one shown below (or something else that lets me uses the methods in the `ios-signing-common` module):

```
import sign = require('ios-signing-common/ios-signing-common');
```

That import is used in another file in another project:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/XamariniOS/xamarinios.ts, however that project is also the same as the ios-signing-common exists in.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/Common/ios-signing-common/ios-signing-common.ts

So is it possible to import the `ios-signing-common` module into the `app-store-promote` file?

I have tried adding the github path "Microsoft/vsts-tasks" as dependency in package.json, and it downloads it to node_modules, but I still can't resolve the `ios-signing-common` module.

I hope that any of you can lead me to a solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I just needed to read up on how module resolving works.

I solved it by adding vsts-tasks as dependency in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "vsts-task-lib": "^0.9.7",
    "vsts-tasks": "Microsoft/vsts-tasks"
  },
```

Then I changed the require path to the following:

```
import sign = require('Agent.Tasks/Tasks/Common/ios-signing-common/ios-signing-common');
```

And it works!

**EDIT** - It could compile, but doesn't seem to work when I run it. It fails in the script because it can't find `Agent.Tasks/Tasks/Common/ios-signing-common/ios-signing-common`.